# How to check accuracy of LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

### The intent:

I am trying to implement an LSTM model that predicts the change of a bounding box given an action.

#### The inputs I have are:

- Action
- bounding box point 0
- bounding box point 1
- bounding box point 2
- bounding box point 3
- class id
- score

I have a dataset that has 5 rows episode (each episode takes 5 rows of the dataset) and the 1st action of the episodes are always 0 (the start action) and the action to predict is the 5th.

### The dataset:

```
act b0  b1  b2  b3  id  score

0   85  238 129 256 69  0.9289865493774414
1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
3   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1                 //row to to predict//
0   46  136 256 245 73  0.9369892477989197
1   18  18  256 252 73  0.8203921318054199
1   144 212 169 223 10  0.9630357623100281
1   13  9   252 199 73  0.9374213814735413
3   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1                 //row to predict//
0   215 141 255 233 72  0.9941028952598572
2   199 116 243 183 74  0.8685483932495117
3   215 141 255 233 72  0.9941184520721436
1   189 78  215 95  76  0.8610376119613647
3   206 50  255 169 72  0.8224002122879028 //row to predict//
0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
3   19  129 249 253 73  0.8635225892066956
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2   0   78  13  91  10  0.9488454461097717
3   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1                 //row to predict//
0   206 123 255 189 62  0.9980332255363464
2   221 197 256 255 62  0.9782524704933167
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
2   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1                 //row to predict//
0   184 78  243 169 72  0.9953457713127136
2   191 139 254 246 72  0.9929528832435608
3   184 78  243 169 72  0.9953963160514832
3   197 1   254 91  72  0.9956125020980835
2   184 78  243 169 72  0.9953963160514832 //row to predict//
```

`-1` is the absence of a bounding box.

### The code:

The code I currently have is a result of a youtube tutorial found on how to have multiple inputs for the LSTM: [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=143&v=FlVJo7LbOzY&feature=emb_logo)

#### Building the model:

```
def buildModel(episode_length, actions_to_predict):
    action = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='action')
    b0 = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='b0')
    b1 = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='b1')
    b2 = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='b2')
    b3 = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='b3')
    class_id = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='class_id')
    score = Input(shape=(episode_length, 1), name='score')

    action_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=(episode_length, 1), return_sequences=False)(action)
    b0_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=(episode_length, 1), return_sequences=False)(b0)
    b1_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=(episode_length, 1), return_sequences=False)(b1)
    b2_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=(episode_length, 1), return_sequences=False)(b2)
    b3_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=(episode_length, 1), return_sequences=False)(b3)
    class_id_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=class_id.shape, return_sequences=False)(class_id)
    score_layers = LSTM(64, input_shape=(episode_length, 1), return_sequences=False)(score)

    output = concatenate(
                [
                    action_layers,
                    b0_layers,
                    b1_layers,
                    b2_layers,
                    b3_layers,
                    class_id_layers,
                    score_layers,
                ]
            )

    output = Dense(actions_to_predict, activation='linear', name='weighted_average_output')(output)

    model = Model(
        inputs=
        [
            action,
            b0,
            b1,
            b2,
            b3,
            class_id,
            score

        ],
        outputs=
        [
            output,
            output,
            output,
            output,
        ]
    )

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=["acc"])

    return model
```

#### Preparing the dataset:

```
# Split the data 80% training and 20% test
per_80 = int(data.shape[0]/ACTIONS_IN_EPISODE/100*80*ACTIONS_IN_EPISODE)
train, test = data[:per_80].copy(), data[per_80:].copy()

def prepareData(dataset):
    column_names = ['index', 'act', 'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'class_id', 'score']
    x, y = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names), pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

    i_start = dataset.index.values[0]

    # Divide the in training actions and the one to predict
    for i in range(dataset.shape[0]):
        if i%ACTIONS_IN_EPISODE-1 == 0: 
            y = y.append(dataset.loc[i+i_start])
        else:
            x = x.append(dataset.loc[i+i_start])

    return x, y

x_training, y_training = prepareData(train)
x_test, y_test = prepareData(test)
```

#### reshape the data:

```
actions_to_train = 4
actions_to_predict = 1

model = buildModel(actions_to_train, actions_to_predict)

action_train = np.array(x_training["act"])
b0_train =  np.array(x_training["b0"])
b1_train =  np.array(x_training["b1"])
b2_train =  np.array(x_training["b2"])
b3_train =  np.array(x_training["b3"])
class_id_train =  np.array(x_training["class_id"])
score_train = np.array(x_training["score"])


action_train = np.reshape(action_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b0_train =  np.reshape(b0_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b1_train =  np.reshape(b1_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b2_train =  np.reshape(b2_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b3_train =  np.reshape(b3_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
class_id_train =  np.reshape(class_id_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
score_train = np.reshape(score_train,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))


action_test = np.array(x_test["act"])
b0_test =  np.array(x_test["b0"])
b1_test =  np.array(x_test["b1"])
b2_test =  np.array(x_test["b2"])
b3_test =  np.array(x_test["b3"])
class_id_test =  np.array(x_test["class_id"])
score_test = np.array(x_test["score"])


action_test = np.reshape(action_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b0_test =  np.reshape(b0_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b1_test =  np.reshape(b1_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b2_test =  np.reshape(b2_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
b3_test =  np.reshape(b3_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
class_id_test =  np.reshape(class_id_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))
score_test = np.reshape(score_test,(-1, actions_to_train, 1))

action_train_y = np.array(y_training["act"])
b0_train_y=  np.array(y_training["b0"])
b1_train_y=  np.array(y_training["b1"])
b2_train_y=  np.array(y_training["b2"])
b3_train_y=  np.array(y_training["b3"])
class_id_train_y=  np.array(y_training["class_id"])
score_train_y= np.array(y_training["score"])

action_train_y = np.reshape(action_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b0_train_y = np.reshape(b0_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b1_train_y = np.reshape(b1_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b2_train_y = np.reshape(b2_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b3_train_y = np.reshape(b3_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
class_id_train_y = np.reshape(class_id_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
score_train_y = np.reshape(score_train_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))


action_test_y = np.array(y_test["act"])
b0_test_y = np.array(y_test["b0"])
b1_test_y = np.array(y_test["b1"])
b2_test_y = np.array(y_test["b2"])
b3_test_y = np.array(y_test["b3"])
class_id_test_y = np.array(y_test["class_id"])
score_test_y = np.array(y_test["score"])


action_test_y = np.reshape(action_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b0_test_y = np.reshape(b0_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b1_test_y = np.reshape(b1_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b2_test_y = np.reshape(b2_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
b3_test_y = np.reshape(b3_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
class_id_test_y = np.reshape(class_id_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
score_test_y = np.reshape(score_test_y,(-1, actions_to_predict, 1))
```

#### Fiting the model:

```
history = model.fit(
    [
        action_train,
        b0_train,
        b1_train,
        b2_train,
        b3_train,
        class_id_train,
        score_train,
    ],
    [
        b0_train_y,
        b1_train_y,
        b2_train_y,
        b3_train_y,
    ],
    validation_data=(
                [   
                    action_test,
                    b0_test,
                    b1_test,
                    b2_test,
                    b3_test,
                    class_id_test,
                    score_test,
                ],
                [
                    b0_test_y,
                    b1_test_y,
                    b2_test_y,
                    b3_test_y,
                ]
            ),
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=3000,
    verbose=1
)
```

#### Output:

```
Epoch 1/100
...

Epoch 100/100
800/800 [==============================] - 0s 157us/step -
loss: 42213.5078 - 
weighted_average_output_loss: 12503.5498 - 
weighted_average_output_acc: 0.0012 - 
weighted_average_output_acc_1: 0.0012 - 
weighted_average_output_acc_2: 0.0000e+00 - 
weighted_average_output_acc_3: 0.0025 - 
val_loss: 31966.8652 - 
val_weighted_average_output_loss: 9189.0039 -
val_weighted_average_output_acc: 0.0050 - 
val_weighted_average_output_acc_1: 0.0000e+00 - 
val_weighted_average_output_acc_2: 0.0000e+00 - 
val_weighted_average_output_acc_3: 0.0000e+00
```

### Questions:

How can I reshape the `Input`s to have a 3D dimension? [solved]

How can I output plots to check accuracy and loss?

#### Edits:

I updated the code, I manage to reshape the `pandas Series` passing the values to a `numpy array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data dimension is correct, you are missing one extra dimension in each of your inputs (filters).

```
rnn.fit(
        [
            x_training["act"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
            x_training["b0"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
            x_training["b1"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
            x_training["b2"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
            x_training["b3"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
            x_training["class_id"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
            x_training["score"].reshape(episode_length, 1)
        ],
        [
            y_training["b_box"]
        ],
        validation_data=(
                    [
                        x_test["act"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
                        x_test["b0"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
                        x_test["b1"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
                        x_test["b2"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
                        x_test["b3"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
                        x_test["class_id"].reshape(episode_length, 1),
                        x_test["score"].reshape(episode_length, 1)        
                    ],
                    [
                        y_test["b_box"]        
                    ]
                ),
        epochs=1,
        batch_size=3200
    )
```

Comment: It won't let me reshape a Series object --> `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'` I added `.values.reshape` and change the `episode_length` with `x_training["act"].values.shape[0]` but still give me the same error

Comment: use, `x_training["act"].numpy().reshape(episode_length, 1)`

Comment: using ` x_training["act"].numpy().reshape(episode_length, 1)` the error i am getting is `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Comment: are you using old pandas? what's your version?

Comment: if I do `reshape(episode_length, 1)` it gives me `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3200 into shape (5,1)`. The dataset contains more episodes and each episode is 5 rows of the dataset

Comment: I updated pandas to `1.0.3` still getting the same error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'numpy'`